# Send an email with the array data the user has filled in a form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, email

I need an html webform that calculates a result according to the user´s chioce (each option has an specific value), and I want to show the user the result´s and email me the options that the user have chosen.

The first part I get it and it works all right, but I cannot make the script to send me the information by mail.

This is an example of my **html form**:

```
1. Place
<select name="place[]">
<option value="zone1">You´re in Zone 1</option>
<option value="zone2">You´re in Zone 2</option>
<option value="zone3">You´re in Zone 3</option>
</select>

1. Role
<select name="role[]">
<option value="role1">You have Role 1</option>
<option value="role2">You have Role 2</option>
<option value="role3">You have Role 3</option>
</select>
```

This is an example of the **php code that I use to sum values** according to what the user have chosen (I have more values in the form):

```
$place = array (
"zone1" => 10,
"zone2" => 20,
"zone3" => 30,
);
$role = array (
"role1" => 1,
"role2" => 2,
"role3" => 3,
);
```

Then I create a variable for each option:

```
$user_place = array();
$user_role = array();
```

Now I tell only to use the information according to what the user has entered:

```
if(is_array($_POST['place']))
{
foreach( $_POST['place'] as $k => $v )
{
   if( isset($place[ $v ]) )
   $user_place [] = $place[ $v ]; 
}
} 

if(is_array($_POST['role']))
{
foreach( $_POST['role'] as $k => $v )
{
   if( isset($role[ $v ]) )
   $user_role [] = $role[ $v ]; 
}
}
```

I create a new variable where each one equals the value assigned to that variable by default, according to the user´s choice:

```
$place_sum = array_sum($user_place);
$role_sum = array_sum($user_role);
```

I sum all of them:

```
$total = $place_sum + $role_sum;
echo $total;
```

Now I want to mail to myself the options each time a user completes the form:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$to   = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'USER RESULTS '.date("m/d/Y h:m:s");
```

Now I've tried:

```
$message = $user_place;
$message = $user_role;
```

And this:

```
$message = join(', ', $_POST['place']);
$message = join(', ', $_POST['role']);
```

And this:

```
$message = $_REQUEST['place'];
$message = $_POST['role'];

mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

And here's my problem: Not any of these options gets me the results. All I get is a blank email and the $message is not mailed.

Comment: Which operating system you are using ?

Comment: Erm... operating system? My server runs on Apache, but I´m using windows XP...

Comment: In CentOS default mail configuration is sendmail, you can send mails by mail() method, i think other OS not support this method. You have to authenticate first.

Comment: But the email is sent... only blank. When I try other stuff (maybe a defult string), it is sent ok.

Comment: I´m somewhat new here, and would like to know what did I do wrong or inaccurate to receive -1 vote (so I won´t do it again in the future). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have your $k and $v reversed. `if( isset($place[ $v ]) )` should be `if( isset($place[ $k ]) )` and so on.

EDIT: Actually, not. Past my bedtime. :-)

Comment: Thanks! So it should be if(is_array($_POST['role']))
{
foreach( $_POST['role'] as $k => $v )
{
   if( isset($role[ $k ]) )
   $user_role [] = $role[ $k ]; 
} I mean, both "v" replaced? Thanks!
}

Comment: Nope, changing those won´t make the total aumont correct (it just bring zero all the time).

Comment: Nope, changing one or both values the answewr is still always zero.

Comment: My bad... your $k and $v were fine. You didn't show your whole form. Is your form method="POST"?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then. Your sample code up there works fine as-is for me (up to `echo $total`). There must be something different in your actual code.

Comment: No, that´s the real deal. I mean, I didn´t change anything (except I cut off some parts of it because the HTML form was way too large). Which one of these should have worked then?: 
$message = $user_place;
$message = $user_role;

$message = join(', ', $_POST['place']);
$message = join(', ', $_POST['role']);

$message = $_REQUEST['place'];
$message = $_POST['role'];

Comment: Ok, I got it printed changing a bit this:

    $message = join(', ', $_POST['place']);

to this:

    $message = join($_POST['place']);

The thing is that the list of items is quite large, and it prints out only one item (even when all fields are filled).

Comment: Ok, just in case anyone wonders, I got it!
This is the way it should get printed:

    $message .= join($_POST['place']); 

Did you just noticed the little dot that´s posted before the "=" sign? Well, that was a world of difference!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case anyone experiences the same thing, finally got it!

This is the way it should get printed:

```
$message .= join($_POST['place']);
```

Did you notice the little dot that's posted before the "=" sign? Well, that was a world of difference.

I don't quite get why it worked with a concatenation-assignment instead the simple assignment, but it worked.